# Menu is disappearing when "settings" link is clicked-CSS

Tags: css

Just tried a small menu with 3 items.("settings","Privacy","About")

When "settings" link is clicked i have created a  menu which appears but goes away immediately..What is the error in code?I'm new to CSS.Any help/alternative idea to solve this is much appreciated.Thanks in advance.

My code:

```css
*{
                margin:0px;
                padding:0px;
            }
            
           
            #settings li {
                list-style: none;
                background-color: black;
                float: left;
                padding: 2px;
                color: white;
                font-size: 18px;
                width:180px;border:1px solid yellow;
                height:50px;
                line-height:20px;
                
            }
    
            #settings ul li:active {
              
                background-color: yellow;
                
            }
            
            #settings ul ul{
                display:none;
            }
            
            #settings ul  li:active > ul {
                display:block;
            }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>

    </head>
    
    <body>
    
    
        <div id="settings">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">settings</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>menu1</li>
                        <li>menu2</li>
                        <li>menu3</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>privacy</li>
                <li>About</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    
    
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Comment: `:active` and `:focus` are the main issues here.

Comment: `:active` ends as soon as the mouse is released.

Comment: you typically use :hover to display submenus, not :active

Comment: To have an element (the dropdown menu) remain after click, assuming that is your intention, you will require javascript.

Comment: It can be done in pure CSS but it requires :focus rather than :active (you also need to move the style to the `a` or make the `li` focusable by adding a tabindex attribute).

Answer (score 1):

try this

```css
*{
                margin:0px;
                padding:0px;
            }
            
           
            #settings li {
                list-style: none;
                background-color: black;
                float: left;
                padding: 2px;
                color: white;
                font-size: 18px;
                width:180px;border:1px solid yellow;
                height:50px;
                line-height:20px;
                
            }
    
            #settings ul li:hover {
          
            background-color: yellow;
            
        }
            
            #settings ul>li:hover ul{
                display: block;
            }
            #settings ul>li ul{
                display:none;
            }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>

    </head>
    
    <body>
    
    
        <div id="settings">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">settings</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>menu1</li>
                        <li>menu2</li>
                        <li>menu3</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>privacy</li>
                <li>About</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    
    
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

"active" state is when you click on the element, but it goes away as soons as you lift the finger.

Use :hover instead and it'll work ;)

```
#settings ul  li:hover > ul {
            display:block;
        }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hkLev6k8/

Edit: same thing, only aesthetic changes 'cause I can't stand the look of default links :p
https://jsfiddle.net/hkLev6k8/5/

Please confirm if you can hover the dropdown without it closing. I'm intrigued 'cause it's working for me in all browsers even down to IE, but I have the feeling it shouldn't.

Comment: This won't work since hovering the submenu will remove it because the 'hover' on the list is gone.

Comment: You'll need to declare the same `:hover` rule for the submenu as well so that it remains visible while hovered over.

Comment: the fiddle "works" until you hover out of the initial ul..... you didn't try to hover the lower menu items?

Comment: @Stuart really? hovering the toggled UL, bellow the main one, and it stays visible.

Comment: certainly didnt work correctly in latest chrome here :/

Comment: wish I could send a screenshot. I'm also on chrome, works OK. Which really got me surprised, as initially I thought :hover on the new UL would be needed too

Comment: we are talking about moving the cursor down, right?

Comment: just ported it to codepen, tested it on all browsers even damn IE, and it works.